# Why dose Google Recaptcha go straight to the tick and not require the puzzle every time?

Tags: php, recaptcha

I am using Google Recaptcha on my website to help secure login. I have noticed that it only requires the puzzle occasionally and will allow users to log in by ticking the box 70% of the time. Could this be an error or is this standard?

Comment: I think it's the standard, puzzle is required generally when you are repeating the same thing again and again.

Comment: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/ says (in one of the slide-in boxes): "reCAPTCHA ...uses advanced risk analysis techniques, considering the user’s entire engagement with the CAPTCHA, and evaluates a broad range of cues that distinguish humans from bots." Which means basically it can sometimes tell that it doesn't need to ask you for the puzzle.

Comment: thanks for the help